# How to Tell if Something Converts Wired into Wifi Connection

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, cable-modem

I am trying to figure out if the following product converts a Regular Cable Modem with No Wifi to a Wifi Connection. It does not specify. What specs can one use, so I can learn myself?

TP-Link AC750 Wireless Portable Nano Travel Router

[https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Wireless-Travel-Router-TL-WR902AC/dp/B01N5RCZQH](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N5RCZQH)

[Picture of product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ6QP.png)

Comment: Have you read [TL-WR902AC | AC750 Wireless Travel WiFi Router | TP-Link United Kingdom](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/3g-usb-adapter/tl-wr902ac/#overview)?

Comment: As per @DavidPostill link - yes, this will do what you want. You need to establish if your modem can have more then 1 device connected to it. If so, you will want to use AP mode, otherwise use it as a router.